# Openlayers and MapQuest from July, 11 2016

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, mapquest

As of yesterday a subscription is needed to use the MapQuest source.
I used to use MapQuest from Openlayers3 but after registering on MapQuest and creating the App, there is no indication on how to use the App Key and App Secret in Openlayers. Also in Openlayers' online API reference the ol.source.MapQuest is disappeared (!).

Does anybody know what's going on or how to use such Keys in Openlayers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use MapQuest anymore with OpenLayers see: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/9cc724550a65195ea729004f401a559fc30c943d/changelog/v3.17.0.md#olsourcemapquest-removal

Answer (score 0):

You now need to create your map layers with the MapQuest Plugin.

[See Related Answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315300/mapquest-direct-tile-access-discontinued/38324489#38324489)

See if there is any plugin for open layers in 
[MapQuest Documentation](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/open)