# MapQuest : MQ is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, leaflet, mapquest

I had to take over and android app working with phonegap -  leaflet/MapQuest/openstreetmap

It broke because MapQuest stopped direct access to tiles and the map wouldn't show up anymore.

I then added the key and modified the code as suggested here : https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/maps/

I use this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/leaflet-0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="scripts/leaflet-0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.s/mq-map.js?key=validKeyNumberThatIWontReveal"></script>
```

In the following structure :

[image]

And my JS :

```
var popup = L.popup();
                        var geolocationMap = L.map(b, {
                            layers: MQ.mapLayer(),
                            center: [40.731701, -73.993411],
                            zoom: 12
                        });
```

Which workout well when I try it on a browser.

But when I compile on my android phone with Android studio I get this error :

> 'MQ is not defined'

It used to work fine with scripts/vendor/leaflet-0.7.

My wild guess would be : it somehow doesn't reach the library scripts/leaflet-0.7.7 but I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having 2 problems, one of my own and one that could help any reader :

- I wasn't declaring the leaflet script at the right place (the page I declared it in). For reference see : https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/open/
- Problem of URL described there : [mapquest direct tile access discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315300/mapquest-direct-tile-access-discontinued)

For the sake of easiness this is the answer

It's as simple as changing your tileUrl.

Replace this:

> var tileUrl =
>   'http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?x';

with this:

> var tileUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

Then use as before:

> L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {  }).addTo(map);

@Joel Harris

Comment: You are saying that you simply replaced MQ open tiles (discontinued) by OSM tiles. Make sure your app does not generate excessive traffic on those free tiles (see OSM terms). If you _do_ plan high traffic, you should consider a paid plan from commercial services (MapQuest, Mapbox, etc.), or OSM might throttle / forbid your access.